# file.getAbsolutePath() and file.length() returning wrong values

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser

I have a method fileUpload() which opens a FileChooser-Menu. If i select there a file then the absolute path and the filesize is written on the console.
First i try this only with:

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());  // Print: C:\Users\Anonym XY\Desktop\test.txt\C:\Users\Anonym XY\Desktop\test.txt
System.out.println(file.length());   // Print: "0"
```

But for the absolute path i get the absolute path but double printed?! O.o
And for the filesize i get here 0, which is the false size.

If i wirte this:

```
 System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().length());  // Print: "15747840"
```

then i get the right filesize.

My whole method:

```
        public void fileUpload() {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() ,fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());  // Print: "Path: C:\Users\Anonym XY\Desktop\test.txt\C:\Users\Anonym XY\Desktop\test.txt"
                System.out.println("Filesize: " + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().length());  // Print: "Filesize: 15747840"
                System.out.println("Filesize: " + file.length());       // Print: "Filesize: 0"

            }else if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error is in this line:

```
File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

what it essentially does: it combines selected-file with itself: as parent and as child, so you get the path "doubled".

the following solves the problem:

```
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think here the issue is your file creation.

```
File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() ,fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

so instead the above line if you just do

```
  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile()
```

Just to point, I have not try this but why to create 2 objects of file? If you are doing this for checking/learning purpose then use

```
File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem:

```
new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() ,fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

This creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File, java.lang.String)

The new file has size zero and its path is obtained by appending path of 'parent' and 'child' path.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**
file chooser returns a file, no need to create new file.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int showOpenDialog = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (showOpenDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File size: " + f.length());
}
```